# How do I join multiple table in hibernate and call it to a web page?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have three table (I won't use my real table but pseudo tables)

Car table

```
Vin_ID   ColorCode   MakeId   Model
 123      qwer        Audi      A7
 456      asdf        BMW       M5
 789      qwer        Audi      S7
 369      cvbn        Chevy     C9
 ...      ...         ...     ...
```

Paint table

```
Color_Code    Color   MakeId
 qwer         Black    Audi
 asdf         Red      BMW
 qwer         Black    Audi
 cvbn         White    Chevy
 ...           ...     ...
```

Manufacture table

```
MakeId    
 Audi        
 BMW        
 Chevy        
...
```

Car table has VIN_ID as PK, ColorCode as FK to Reference table Paint.Colorcode Pk, and MakeId as FK to Reference table Manufacture.Make.

This is the pojo classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="car")
public class Car {

  @Id
  @JoinColumn(name="vin_id")
  private Paint paint;

  @OneToOne
  @Column(name="colorcode")
  private String colorCode;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="makeid")
  private Manufacture manufacture;

  @Column(name="model")
  private String model;

...constructor and getters and setter...
```

Paint Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="paint")
public class Paint {

  @Id
  @Column(name="colorcode")
  private String colorCode;

  @Column(name="color")
  private String color;

  @Column(name="makeid")
  private String makeId;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="colorcode")
  private Car car;

 ....Constructor and setters and getter...
```

Manufacture table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="manufacture")
public class Manufacture {

  @Id
  @Column(name="Makeid")
  private String MakeId;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="makeid"
  private Car car;

....Constructor and setters and getter...
```

How do i create a join query of the 3 tables in my DAO class (such as example below)  and get the results onto a jsp page.  If I want to display the vinId in my jsp page is pretty forward ${car.vinId},  But how do display the CAR.COLORCODE, and CAR.MAKEID values from POJO class to my jsp.  They are using objects to define the variable?

```
SELECT C. VINID, P.COLOR, M.MAKEID, C.MODEL
FROM CAR C
JOIN PAINT P ON P.COLORCODE = C.COLORCODE
JOIN MANUFACTURE M ON M.MAKEID = C.MAKEID
```

I would like to display C. VINID, P.COLOR, M.MAKEID, C.MODEL values on a jsp.  Please help.

Comment: Do you need the one-to-one mappings to be bi-directional?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your entity classes. 
First, unless you are going to be explicitly querying for child entities and not the full Car entity, you don't need a bi-directional join (i.e. no Car entity in Paint/Manufacture etc). Second, you have an invalid mapping between Car and Paint. You should do something like this:

Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="car")
public class Car {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "vin_id")
  private int vinId;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="colorcode")
  private Paint paint;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="makeid")
  private Manufacture manufacture;

  @Column(name="model")
  private String model;

...constructor and getters and setter...
```

From which you can query the Car entity:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Car where c.vinId = :id");
q.setParameter("id", 1234567890123456);
Car c = q.uniqueValue();
```

And you can access the values you wish via the Car entity in JSTL:

```
${car.vinId}
${car.paint.colorCode}
${car.manufacture.Makeid}
```

Finally, you really shouldn't use string values as primary and foreign keys. That can be a major performance bottleneck, especially when joining tables on said keys. It's a much better practice to use integer values.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  the post was an example and i was haste to post it.  My Pk in each tables are integer sequenced values.